# Unable to compile old project

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods

While trying to compile an iOS app, I receive this error and nothing else, how can I find what is the real problem?
The project has **COCOAPODS**, but it's updated successfully.

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-MyProjectName
```

Comment: please add your pod file here ??

Comment: Did you open the `.xcodeworkspace` and not the `.xcodeproj`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem take many issues :

1- If the project uses CocoaPods be aware to always open the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj` file.

2- check if pod file is valid syntax .

one of these issues case this error .

Answer (score 0):

After `pod install` the repo,

1. Make sure you close the project and open it again via `xcworkspace`, from there i think it would able to find the pod library.
2. If warning still appearing, check in the framework group, if there's `-lpod.Project.a` in red, just delete it and build the project again.

Hope it helps.